# Create new server keys in GCM after September 2016

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging

How to register a new Server key in the GCM after September 2016?
Yes, I understand that the registration of new keys in the GCM is prohibited.

> Starting from September 2016, you can create new server keys only in
>   the Firebase Console using the Cloud Messaging tab of the Settings
>   panel. Existing projects that need to create a new server key can be
>   imported in the Firebase console without affecting their existing
>   configuration.

But our company policy does not allow the use of FCM. 
Perhaps Google office can help?

Comment: As far as I remember you can use GCM with a key generated in FCM. I had to do that in one of my projects because Mixpanel didn't (and doesn't) support FCM

Comment: FCM and GCM are the same thing basically, why does it matter to your company?

Comment: We have confidence in the new brand. Enterprise architect fears that FCM can then be closed

Answer (score 0):

There is no other way to generate a valid Server key to use for GCM or FCM, other than using the one auto-generated one when you create/migrate a Firebase Project in the Firebase Console.

As mentioned in the comments, using a Server Key retrieved from the Firebase Console can still be used by implementations for GCM. Using this *technically* doesn't mean that you're using FCM already.

Also mentioned in the comments, FCM is practically just GCM itself with new features. It is already strongly recommended that users of GCM migrate to using FCM already.

If you're still persistent on not using a Server Key from generating a Firebase Project, I suggest contacting GCM Support through this [form](https://support.google.com/code/contact/gcm_dev_support), providing the details as to why you need to generate a new Server Key.